# how to use where with list of string

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have list of strings like "one" , "two" , "three",

I want to search from a database and select all items that have at least one of them , I want do this by entity framework. To do this I use:

```
 if (SearchVM.Tags.Count > 0)
                //SourceList= SourceList.Where(x=>x.Tags.Where(...));
```

It doesn't work because it's wrong and incomplete.

By T-sql is :

```
select * from SourceList where tagname in (select name from SearchList)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var SearchList= new List<string>{"one" , "two" , "three" };
var result = dataContext.SourceList.Where(p => p.Tags.Any(t => SearchList.Contains(t.TagName)));
```

`Contains` will be translated to `IN` statement

Comment: I think `Contains ` translated to `Like` statement ,

Comment: Since EF 6 it's translated to `IN`